# Fiddler Dynatrace integration

Tags: fiddler, dynatrace

I added request header in fiddler by using the syntax below:

```
oSession.oRequest["NewHeaderName"] = "New header value";
```

Ex:  `oSession.oRequest["Test"] = "DT";`

I could see the header in fiddler, but unable to see the same in "Tagged web request"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to work this code should be in the OnBeforeRequest method. Is it there?

Also if there are other proxies between Fiddler and Dynatrace they ight remove the header. The chance for that happening increases if this is some standard HTTP header. Have in mind that if your system had a proxy set before running Fiddler then Fiddler will automatically use the original system proxy as an upstream proxy.